# Armazenamento de variáveis em PHP - $_SESSION x $_GET

Tags: php, session, variáveis, get

**Olá amigos.**
Tenho uma dúvida sobre boas práticas aplicadas em desenvolvimento:
Qual seria a melhor forma de armazenamento temporário de variáveis numa aplicação?
Tenho uma aplicação PHP em que posso editar usuários, onde basta que eu clique no link e me direciona para a página de edição onde o ID é recuperado através da query string usuario.

```
http://www.app.com.br?usuario=23
```

Esta seria a melhor forma? Ou seria melhor armazená-la em uma variável de sessão?
Agradeço a ajuda!

Comment: Desde que não permita que eu altere o `23` para `24` e deixe eu alterar configurações alheias não há problema. O StackOverflow usa isto, [`/edit/15089`](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/edit/15089), o `15089` é o meu ID. Se você não estiver conectado na minha conta irá dar erro, é justamente isso que deve ocorrer na sua aplicação, prevenir que outras pessoas altere configurações de outras pessoas.

Comment: Assim como o @Inkeliz falou, você pode salvar em qualquer lugar, embora no GET seja mais usado para esse tipo de situação.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Com `$_GET` tu só vais ter acesso à variável, neste com o caso com valor `23` no serviço `http://www.app.com.br?usuario=23`, porque no `http://www.app.com.br?usuario=24` já não vais ter a tua variável com o valor `23`, mas sim `24`.

Dito isto, para guardares uma variável temporariamente ao longo de toda a tua aplicação, deves usar [session](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp) ou [cookies](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_cookies.asp).

Neste caso se quiseres guardar o valor `$_GET['usuario']` em uma sessão, fazes (isto é uma maneira muito básica):

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['usuario'] = $_GET['usuario'];
```

Em que terás acesso em todas as restantes páginas, se colocares no topo de todas elas `session_start()`.

Mas isto não faz muito sentido para mim (pelo que percebi), porque se o utilizador depois for ao url `http://www.app.com.br?usuario=24` , a variável `$_SESSION['usuario']` passa agora a ter o valor `24` .

A minha dica, caso o usuário `23` não puder visualizar `http://www.app.com.br?usuario=24` é guardares esse id desde o login em sessão e fazeres a verificação nessa página:

```
<?php
session_start();
if($_SESSION['usuario'] != $_GET['usuario']) {
    header('Location: OUTRA_PAG.php');
    die();
}
```